# Solidworks PDM Run PDM template with parameters

Tags: api, solidworks

I would like to run a template in the solidworks PDM via API.

I can to do it by

```
IEdmTemplate5 template = null;
template.run(this.Handle.ToInt32(), vault1.RootFolderID);
```

but this template require input normaly filled by the user.
How can I run the template with this parameter by code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the EPDM template run command will show a popup of the template card window and not allow you to programmatically set values to the template prior to running it.  The only way to run an unattended will be to eliminate the input parameters specified on the card and mimic any template actions using api calls.